# How do I select rows in 1 table containing keywords from another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, indexing, sas, keyword, contains

I have two tables - one with sentences, and another with keywords. I would like to select rows from the sentences table that contain any of the keywords.

For Example:

Sentences

- I like my dog
- My favorite food is pasta
- Programming is fun

Key Words

- favorite food
- dog

My goal is for the the first 2 rows to return.

So far I have:

```
select a.*

from sentences a

join keywords b

on a.sentences like '%' || b.keywords || '%'
```

However I am getting the error "the execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins that can not be optimized"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Also not sure if it matters much but I am doing this on SAS 9.4

Comment: The error tells u how to get the solution

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0o4a5ac71mcchn1kc1zhxdnm139.htm

Comment: Is that an error or a note? Since you need to compare every record to every other record in the table it is a cartesian join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently joining/merging based on matching part of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708680/efficiently-joining-merging-based-on-matching-part-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues to protect against in this kind of code but the primary concerns are: leading and trailing spaces in the search keywords, character case matching (most SAS character comparisons are case sensitive), duplicate matches (multiple keywords matching one sentence).

The code pattern below should deal with these issues.

```
select distinct a.*
from sentences a cross join keywords b
where findw(a.sentences,b.keywords,' ','ir');
```

The "distinct" argument will remove duplicate matches while the findw function specifies to use spaces ' ' as the only delimiter of concern and the 'ir" specifies to be case insensitive ( modifier 'i') and remove leading and trailing delimiters/spaces (modifier 'r' combined with designation of ' ' as the delimiter).

Depending upon the data sizes involved you might see better performance by using a data step and a hash table. This would allow you to stop testing a sentence on the first keyword match. The sql code tests every sentence against every keyword.